# 'floor' value of hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash with a default value of 0: `Hash.new(0)`

Assuming an integer value, is there a way to set a 'floor', such that if the value goes below the floor, that floor is returned?

example:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
h.floor = 0

h[:five] += 5
h[:five] 
#=> 5

h[:negative_five] -= 5
h[:negative_five] 
#=> 0
```

Comment: Should the floor be returned or the value for the key never go below the floor (ie is h[:negative_five] + 8 equal to 3 or equal to 8)?

Comment: in this case, it could be just the value returned, so `h[:negative_five] + 8 == 8`  but that's a very good point

Comment: I think this is a bad idea. Here's an example of the implications, assuming @Thomas' solution. Suppose `h = {a: -1}; m = MyHash.new; m[:b] = -2;  m.floor = 0; hm = h.merge(m) #=> {:a=>-1, :b=>-2}; mh = m.merge(h) #=> {:b=>-2, :a=>-1}; hm==mh #=> true`. Then `hm.class #=> Hash; hm[:b] #=> -2` and `mh.class #=> MyHash; mh[:b] #=> ArgumentError`. Why the exception? Because we have not set `mh.floor = 0`. Wouldn't it be easier and less problematic to use a dead-simple method: `def max_of_value_and_floor(h,k,floor); (h[k] < floor) ? floor : h[k]`?. This also allows the floor to vary by key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation

```
class MyHash < Hash
    attr_writer :floor

    def [](key)
        # you can use one of those two lines or your own code in case the floor hasn't been define
        # raise 'floor value must be defined' if @floor.nil?
        # super key if @floor.nil?
        value = (fetch(key) < @floor ? @floor : fetch(key))
    end
end
```

Comment: instead of defining `floor=` method by hand, it's possible to use `attr_writer :floor`.

Comment: This is a valid implementation for the question, but the comments make it invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a new implementation, reflecting that you should not store any value below the floor :

```
class FlooredHash < Hash
  attr_writer :floor

  def floor
    @floor || -(2 ** 32) # setting the default floor for all FlooredHashes
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    super(key, [value, floor].max)
  end
end
```

Be aware that you would have to redefine `#store` as well if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm using this:

```
def enforce_floor!(hash, floor)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    hash[key] = floor if value < floor
  end
end
```

It works, but I think maybe there is a more elegant solution